# Variation of $f(x)=x^2-\sqrt{x}$ over $(0;\infty)$ without using derivative (For student didn't get derivation method)?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, calculus-of-variations, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Am looking to study varition of $f(x)=x^2-\sqrt{x}$ over $(0;\infty)$ without using derivative sign or anything related to derivative function, I want for example using inequalities .
We have  $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=0$ then we have f is increasing and decreasing in $(0,1]$ then we must subdivise  $(0,1]$ in $(0,a]$,$[a,1], a\in \mathbb{R}$ , for $[a,\infty[$ we have :$f(a) < f(+\infty) $ its little clear that is increasing in that domain , But how I can show its variation for student didn't get derivation method over $(0;\infty)$?

**Note:** Student didn't get inverse function definition

Comment: Hint: $x^2$ and $\sqrt{x}$ are inverse functions so that relatively to the curve $y=x\cdots$

Comment: Student didn't know also inverse function , I know that

Comment: another idea is growing speed of both functions compared... or concavity - convexity or ... (they must know something!)

Comment: another one using inequalities : $\;f(x^2)=(x^3-1)\,x\,$ so that for $x>1\cdots$ and for $x<1\cdots$

Comment: Pleas could u show me that as answer

Answer (score 1):

We may start with (for $x>0$) :
$\displaystyle\;f(x^2)=x^4-x=(x^3-1)\,x\,$

resolve the case $x=1$ and use inequalities for the remaining cases :

- for $x>1$ we have $\;x^3>1\,$ so that $\;(x^3-1)>0$.
  We thus have the product of two increasing positive functions that will also be increasing since $\;\displaystyle f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)=[f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x+h)]+[f(x)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)]$
- for $0<x<1$ we have $\;0<x^3<1\;$ and things are more complicated since $\,1-x^3\,$ is decreasing while $\,x\,$ is increasing. The function $\,x\mapsto x^4-x\,$ goes from $\,0\,$ to $\,0\,$ in $\,(0,1)\,$ so let's see if it may be rewritten as $\,P(x)(x-k)^2+c\,$ with $P(x)$ a polynomial.
  The idea is that the tangent at $\,x=k\,$ will be horizontal with ordinate equal to $\,c\,$ (this is clear in general since its (forbidden) derivative will have a factor $(x-k)\;$).
  $P(x):=x^2+ax+b\,$ (what else?) gives us :
  \begin{align}
  x^4-x&=(x^2+ax+b)(x-k)^2+c\\
  0&=(a-2k)x^3+(b+k^2-2ak)x^2+(ak^2-2bk+1)x+c+bk^2\\
  a&=2k,\,b=3k^2,\,c=-3k^4,\;k^3=\dfrac 14\quad(\text{from}\ \ 2k^3-6k^3+1=0) \\
  f(x^2)&=((x+k)^2+2k^2)(x-k)^2-3k^4\quad\text{with}\ \ k=\dfrac 1{\sqrt[3]4}\\
  \end{align}
  I'll let you conclude.

Comment: But how student can get the accurate range for that function when it decreasing ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: I edited my answer with the accurate minimum but must add that avoiding derivatives is rather a "tour de force" (as you probably noticed! :-)). Fine continuation,

Comment: A possibly clearer derivation for the case $x<1$ : for $\;g(x):=x^4-x\;$ we consider $\displaystyle g(k+h)-g(k)=(k+h)^4-k^4-h=4kh^3+6k^2h^2+4k^3h-h=(4kh+6k^2)h^2+(4k^3-1)h\;$ so that for $\,4k^3=1\,$ we obtain $\;g(k+h)=g(k)+((2k+h)^2+2k^2)h^2\,$ and conclude that $g(k)$ is a minimum of $g(x)$ for $\,0<x<1\,$ with $\,x:=k+h$.

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM
$$x^2-\sqrt{x}=x^2+\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{256}}-\sqrt{x}-\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{256}}\geq$$
$$\geq4\sqrt[4]{x^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{256}}\right)^3}-\sqrt{x}-\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{256}}=-\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{256}}.$$
Can you end it now?